# Loading photos with latitude and longitude?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-pro, garmin, photos

I am new to Garmin and have not worked with them.

However my specialist took a lot of photos that have latitude and longitude into ArcGIS 10.3.1 or ArcGIS Pro

Has anyone done this previously?

Comment: This question would be fine to ask as-is in the GIS Chat Room but is too broad for focussed Q&A.  I think this partly because I recommend treating ArcGIS Pro and ArcGIS Desktop separately when interpreting "one question per question" but mainly because asking if anyone has done something invites a host of answers like "not that I know of", "yeah, me", and "me too" (all expanded in some way of course).

Comment: You can closed it if you want. I should have google first before ask a question... so I found this . http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0912/import-geotagged-photographs-into-arcmap.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a **[Photos toolset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-photos-toolset.htm)** in ArcGIS. I think what you're trying to do is create points from photo locations.  To do that, use the **[Geotagged Photos to Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/geotagged-photos-to-points.htm)** tool.

Here's an article to **[Import Geotagged Photos](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0912/import-geotagged-photographs-into-arcmap.html)** into ArcMap.